# Displaying cookie value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to display cookie value in javascript. I would like to alertvwhatever the user types in the input box  as the cookie value.
My code is as follows;

```
<body>
<script>
function WriteCookie(){
    if(document.myform.customer.value=""){
        alert("Write something in the text input.");
        return;
    }

    var cookievalue=escape(document.myform.customer.value) + ";";
    document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
    alert("Setting cookie:" + "name=" + cookievalue);

}
</script>
<form name="myform" action="">
Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer"/>
<input type="button" value="Set Cookie" onclick="WriteCookie();"/>
</form>

</body>
```

In this examples,whenever the user click the button, WriteCookie() is called.This function checks whether or not the input is empty or not. If not emplty, it tried to grab the text and store it in cookievalue variable.Escape function then makes the text input portable along with ";" attaching to the end of the string. Now,then i set cookie with document.cookie function. When I alet the cookie in the next step, the cookie does not show up. Plz what is wrong ?

Comment: You don't need to attach ";"

Comment: You have a typo. `if(document.myform.customer.value="")` should use `==`, not `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
 <body>
<script>
    function WriteCookie(){
    if(document.myform.customer.value==""){
        alert("Write something in the text input.");
        return;
        }

    alert(document.cookie);

            var cookievalue=escape(document.myform.customer.value) + ";";
            document.cookie="name=" + cookievalue;
            alert("Setting cookie:" + "name=" + cookievalue);

        }
</script>
<form name="myform" action="">
Enter name: <input type="text" name="customer"/>
<input type="button" value="Set Cookie" onclick="WriteCookie();"/>
</form>

</body>
```